# Congruence equation of the form $ax^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: congruences

I'm trying to solve $13j^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{264}$.
Now I've seen the form $x^2 \equiv n \pmod{m}$ but the form $ax^2 \equiv n \pmod{m}$ although it looks like a quadratic congruent equation, I don't seem to be able to follow exactly the same steps as $ax^2 +bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.
Some help would be appreciated (with detail and explanations). Thank you in advance.

Comment: I agree but how do I solve that then?

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** because $\gcd(13, 264)=1$ [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) $13x+264y=1$ [has $(61,-3)$ as a solution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-diophantine-equations-one-equation/), thus $13\cdot 61 \equiv 1 \pmod{264}$ and 
$$13 j^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{264} \iff 13\cdot61 j^2 \equiv61 \pmod{264} \iff\\
j^2 \equiv61 \pmod{264}$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. To find j from j squared, I can't find a perfect square by adding 61 + 264, then 61 +2(264)....61+n(264). I didn't try 264 numbers...is there a way to do that easier and faster?

Comment: There is no solution, see the last theorem in [this chapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Composite_modulus) and $264$ is divisible by $8$.